# Admob dependency conflict

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, google-play-services

There seems to an ongoing issue with Android's google play services, base, analytics, admob, etc - everything under `com.google.android.gms:`

The `gms` library is dependent on version `26.x` of the android support library, the latest version being `28.0.0`

This results in gradle merge conflicts, and warning (which present as errors but compiles)

[image]

How would you suggest approaching the issue? This is an ongoing issue a fix has not been issued in quite some time.

Answer (score -2):

Update the library to the newest Version.